# Different width slides in nuxt-swiper

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have used a nuxt-swiper, and I am attempting to create a carousel that contains slides of varying widths. The nuxt-swiper component sets the width of the slides automatically. However, I require different-width slides, and thus I have utilized the !important CSS property to modify the width of each slide. This approach has proven effective, as demonstrated in the following image:

[image]

Regrettably, the carousel does not end when the user reaches the last slide, and it allows the user to slide beyond the intended endpoint, which I believe is caused by the CSS property modifications I made. However, I am uncertain about how to achieve the desired result through alternative methods. I am hoping for guidance on how to conclude the carousel when the user reaches its conclusion.

[image]

I have attempted to utilize the :slides-per-view="auto" property, but it has not produced the desired outcome and worked the same as :slides-per-view="1", the default value. I have also experimented with the :width="600" property, but it makes the carousel not responsive. Is it feasible to establish a function that calculates the ":width" value based on the user's display? If so, I am uncertain about the appropriate algorithm to use. Any assistance you may provide would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I tried using "slides-per-view='auto'" and it works better, but the last slide is cut in half. How can i fix that?

Comment: add single quote to your property as `'auto'` should be a string. so `:slides-per-view="'auto'"`. 
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rm296y?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue